# Change Visual Studio project property Start action to "Don't open page" in several projects

Tags: vb.net, powershell, visual-studio-2019, batch-processing, projects-and-solutions

When I first download our solution from the version control server, I need to set every project Start action property manually. I would like to know if there is any 'unattended' way to do this. I don't mind creating a batch or powershell script, even opening every needed file and search and replace, assuming this property would be in plain text. I wasn't able to find it in the vbproj file.

Comment: It wouldn't be in the project file because it's not a project setting. That's why you need to set it yourself after pulling the source. It's a per-user setting so it will be in one of the per-user files that is not committed to source control. I don't know exactly which one but there aren't that many of them so it shouldn't be too hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vbproj.user the property is `<StartAction>`, you must change it's value to `NoStartPage`.
I ended up putting together a powershell script (based on other answers at stackOverflow) to help me out with that.

```
gci -r -include "*.vbproj.user" |
 foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) |
 foreach-object { $_ -replace "(?<=<StartAction>).*(?=<\/StartAction>)", "NoStartPage" }  | 
set-content $a }
```